# Api-Platform missing "servers" configuration key in api_platform.yaml

Tags: php, postman, openapi, api-platform.com, symfony-4.2

On Api Platform configuration page `servers` key is missing.

More info here:

- https://api-platform.com/docs/core/configuration/
- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/

I need to find a solution to add servers to the /api/docs.json?spec_version=3 without manually doing it every time

Right now I am downloading the file from a browser and then add the missing key manually - it works but it is not what I want.

`{"openapi":"3.0.2","servers":[{"url":""}],...`

I am searching for the best solution with the least effort for a new developer that wants to use the openapi documentation.

Comment: I guess a [Swagger Decorator](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-openapi-specification) can do that

Comment: I think it should be done in more sophisticated way.